# can resolveWithFullResponse: true make response heavier network-wise?

Tags: npm, http-headers, request-promise

https://github.com/request/request-promise
I want to measure and possibly minimise the payload of response.
 So I want to get content-length header. I will not get header unles i specify `resolveWithFullResponse` to request. The question is, how it works, in detail? Can it make server response larger in terms of network load?
When i get specific page with browser, i got different (3 times smaller, in my case) content-length header value, compared to getting the same page with request-promise with `resolveWithFullResponse: true`.
So is request-promise just trim response it gets, if you do not specify `resoveWithFullResponse`, or it requests more data in case it is set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`resolveWithFullResponse` just means that instead of receiving the response body in your `.then`, you'll receive the full `IncomingMessage` object for the response, with all the headers, status codes, and other attached information instead.

It does not affect the network request being made.